# Time-based spacing constraints in Gekko

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, gekko, mixed-integer-programming

I'm trying to constrain the vector output of "simu_total_volume" below by requiring that solution output elements (x7=1) be spaced apart by s records (weeks) while also controlling for the maximum number of times x7 can be = 1 in total.

The code below seems to work but I'm noticing a reduction in the sum of x7 from 10 (without the spacing requirement) to 8 (with the spacing requirement) despite there being enough space for sum(x7) to = 10 given the constraints. I can also manually arrange the full solution space and here and come up with a more optimal solution in Excel, so I'm not sure why Gekko isn't finding it.

Here are the full details to reproduce locally (tested for accuracy):

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.options.NODES = 3
m.options.IMODE = 3
m.options.MAX_ITER = 1000

lnuc_weeks = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

min_promo_price = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3]

max_promo_price = [3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5,3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5]

base_srp = [3.48, 3.48, 3.48, 3.48, 3.0799, 3.0799, 3.0799, 3.0799,3.0799, 3.0799, 3.0799, 3.0799, 3.0799, 3.0799, 3.0799, 3.0799, 3.0799, 3.0799, 3.0799]

lnuc_min_promo_price = 1.99

lnuc_max_promo_price = 1.99

coeff_fedi = [0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589,0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589, 0.022589]

coeff_feao = [0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995, 0.02929995]

coeff_diso = [0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338, 0.05292338]

sumproduct_base = [0.20560305, 0.24735297, 0.24957423, 0.23155435, 0.23424058,0.2368096 , 0.27567109, 0.27820648, 0.2826393 , 0.28660598, 0.28583971, 0.30238505, 0.31726649, 0.31428312, 0.31073792, 0.29036779, 0.32679041, 0.32156337, 0.24633734]

neg_ln = [[0.14842000515],[0.14842000512],[0.14842000515],[0.14842000512],[-0.10407483058],[0.43676249024],[0.43676249019],[0.43676249024],[0.43676249019],[0.43676249024],[0.43676249019], [0.026284840258],[0.026284840291],[0.026284840258],[0.026284840291], [0.026185109811],[0.026284840258],[0.026284840291],[0.026284840258]]

neg_ln_ppi_coeff = [1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879,1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879,1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879, 1.22293879]

base_volume = [124.38, 193.2, 578.72, 183.88, 197.42, 559.01, 67.68, 110.01,60.38, 177.11, 102.65, 66.02, 209.83, 81.22, 250.44, 206.44, 87.99, 298.95, 71.07]

week = pd.Series([13, 14, 17, 18, 19, 26, 28, 33, 34, 35, 39, 42, 45, 46, 47, 48, 50, 51, 52])


n = 19

x1 = m.Array(m.Var,(n), integer=True) #LNUC weeks

i = 0
for xi in x1:
    xi.value = lnuc_weeks[i]
    xi.lower = 0
    xi.upper = lnuc_weeks[i]
    i += 1

x2 = m.Array(m.Var,(n)) #Blended SRP

i = 0
for xi in x2:
    xi.value = 5
    m.Equation(xi >= m.if3((x1[i]) - 0.5, min_promo_price[i], lnuc_min_promo_price))
    m.Equation(xi <= m.if3((x1[i]) - 0.5, max_promo_price[i], lnuc_max_promo_price))
    i += 1
x3 = m.Array(m.Var,(n), integer=True) #F&D
x4 = m.Array(m.Var,(n), integer=True) #FO
x5 = m.Array(m.Var,(n), integer=True) #DO
x6 = m.Array(m.Var,(n), integer=True) #TPR

#Default to F&D
i = 0
for xi in x3:
    xi.value = 1
    xi.lower = 0
    xi.upper = 1
    i += 1

i = 0
for xi in x4:
    xi.value = 0
    xi.lower = 0
    xi.upper = 1
    i += 1

i = 0
for xi in x5:
    xi.value = 0
    xi.lower = 0
    xi.upper = 1
    i += 1

i = 0
for xi in x6:
    xi.value = 0
    xi.lower = 0
    xi.upper = 1
    i += 1

x7 = m.Array(m.Var,(n), integer=True) #Max promos

i = 0
for xi in x7:
    xi.value = 1
    xi.lower = 0
    xi.upper = 1
    i += 1

x = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7]

neg_ln=[m.Intermediate(-m.log(x[1][i]/base_srp[i])) for i in range(n)]

total_vol_fedi  =[m.Intermediate(coeff_fedi[0]+ sumproduct_base[i] + (neg_ln[i]*neg_ln_ppi_coeff[0])) for i in range(n)]
total_vol_feao  =[m.Intermediate(coeff_feao[0]+ sumproduct_base[i] + (neg_ln[i]*neg_ln_ppi_coeff[0])) for i in range(n)]
total_vol_diso  =[m.Intermediate(coeff_diso[0]+ sumproduct_base[i] + (neg_ln[i]*neg_ln_ppi_coeff[0])) for i in range(n)]
total_vol_tpro  =[m.Intermediate(sumproduct_base[i] + (neg_ln[i]*neg_ln_ppi_coeff[0])) for i in range(n)]

simu_total_volume = [m.Intermediate((
(m.max2(0,base_volume[i]*(m.exp(total_vol_fedi[i])-1)) * x[2][i] +
m.max2(0,base_volume[i]*(m.exp(total_vol_feao[i])-1)) * x[3][i] +
m.max2(0,base_volume[i]*(m.exp(total_vol_diso[i])-1)) * x[4][i] +
m.max2(0,base_volume[i]*(m.exp(total_vol_tpro[i])-1)) * x[5][i]) + base_volume[i]) * x[6][i]) for i in range(n)]


[m.Equation(x3[i] + x4[i] + x5[i] + x6[i] == 1) for i in range(i)]

#Limit max promos
m.Equation(sum(x7)<=10)

#Enforce spacing
s=1
for s2 in range(1, s+1):
    for i in range(0, n-s2):
        f = week[week == week[i] + s2].index
        if len(f)>0:
            m.Equation(x7[i] + x7[f[0]]<=1)

m.Maximize(m.sum(simu_total_volume))

m.options.SOLVER=1

m.solve(disp = True)
```

Comment: Not reproducible; `m` is undefined

Comment: Excellent suggestion by @Reinderien to include reproducible code. Thanks for posting the full problem, datadude558

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enforce a spacing constraint with a summation over a subset of the periods with a moving window such as:

```py
m.Equation(sum(x[0:3])<=1)
m.Equation(sum(x[1:4])<=1)
m.Equation(sum(x[2:5])<=1)
```

Here is a test that shows solutions with different spacing constraints with a maximum of 4 out of the 5 selected. The spacing constraints are successively [0,1,2,3]:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

for s in [0,1,2,3]:
    n = 5
    x = m.Array(m.Var,n,integer=True,value=1,lb=0,ub=1)
    m.Equation(sum(x)<=4)
    for i in range(0,n-s):
       m.Equation(sum(x[i:i+s+1])<=1)
       
    m.Maximize(sum(x))

    m.options.SOLVER=1
    m.solve(disp=False)
    print(f'spacing: {s} solution: {x}')
```

The solution is:

```
spacing: 0 solution: [[0.0] [1.0] [1.0] [1.0] [1.0]]
spacing: 1 solution: [[1.0] [0.0] [1.0] [0.0] [1.0]]
spacing: 2 solution: [[0.0] [1.0] [0.0] [0.0] [1.0]]
spacing: 3 solution: [[1.0] [0.0] [0.0] [0.0] [1.0]]
```

There are multiple solutions for the case with spacing 0 and 2 and unique solutions for spacing 1 and 3. The solver returns just one of the solutions for each case. You may need to add an additional objective if there is a preference to select earlier slots.

Comment: Thank you! So "m.Equation(sum(x[i:i+s+1])<=1)" does work but it seems it's not returning any of the optimal subsets that I'm finding manually (I also did a Bayesian optimization on it and it never found anything better).

I went ahead just posted the full detail to the issue so you can copy and paste the question code and it should run locally. You'll see an output of "-4226" but I can get 5041 just by manually arranging the solution space to respect the spacing and frequency requirements.

Really appreciate the guidance and guessing I'm just missing something.

Comment: One thing to try is plug in the best solution and use constraints at those values to test the equations. This helps to validate the equations to ensure that the best manual solution is feasible. Exhaustive, heuristic, and integer programming are three ways to obtain a solution: https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/ScheduleOptimization  Heuristic solutions are often a great way to obtain an initial guess for the integer programming approach.

Comment: Added some index lookup logic to get around the unevenly spaced, seems to be working in this new loop.